# Why prefer ListAdapter over ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android

> I saw a video using `ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter()`
>   instead of `ArrayAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter()`. Why?
>
> Why is `ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter()` valid when the
>   constructor is not constructing an instance of `ListAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a simple example. Its all inheritance and parent child thing.
Study the below given code and you will get everything.

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Dog d = new Dog();

        Animal a2 = d; // OK, since Dog IS-A Animal
        Dog d2 = a; // not OK; what if a is a Cat?
    }
}
```

So objects of Parent class can hold objects of child class. The reverse could not be true.

In your case `ListAdapter` is parent interface and `ArrayAdapter` is indirect subclass of it.

You can see full hierarchy here
[ListAdater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: Oh thanks but I don't understand why parents class/ ListAdapter can use the child class constructor like how ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(). Isn't this not the right constructor?

Comment: Because if A extends B, then you can write `B myObj = new A();`. The same is for interfaces